# how to filter documents with a field containing a substring

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have a document containing the following field:

```
  "data": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
```

and when performing a query on kibana I want to filter all the documents having a substring like `sendMessageFromAgent`. I don't want to perform a query, I want to filter them.

An example of the field is the following:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><S:Body><ns2:sendMessageFromAgent xmlns:ns2="http://blahblah/"><ns2:session><ns2:id>a-session-id</ns2:id></ns2:session><ns2:userId><ns2:id>624962268835</ns2:id></ns2:userId><ns2:messages><ns2:message><ns2:text>we have some text here</ns2:text><ns2:sentTimeMillis>1288851099000</ns2:sentTimeMillis></ns2:message></ns2:messages></ns2:sendMessageFromAgent></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

I've tried to place the following DSL query as a new kibana filter but nothing is returned:

```
{
  "wildcard": {
    "data": "*sendMessageFromAgent*"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy-peasy: add a kibana filter and use the following DSL:

```
{
  "match": {
    "data": {
      "operator": "AND",
      "query": "sendMessageFromAgent <other-strings-if-needed>"
    }
  }
}
```

this performs a full-text search on the `data` field